# How to change index?

Tags: sql-server, command

I want to column index change.

For example:

Column name: MemberID

Sample data:

```
MemberID1: M100045
MemberID2: M100046
MemberID3: M100047
```

Expected results:

```
Member ID1: T200045
Member ID2: T200046
Member ID3: T200047
```

How I do change 5 index SQL query?

Comment: This question doesn't really makes sense.... Do you just want to replace the 'M1' with 'T2'? If so look at `REPLACE`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

The index will be updated when the data is updated. Thus, you just need to update the data.

```
update YourTable
set yourColumn = stuff(yourColumn,1,2,'T2')
```

[`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) inserts a string into another string, and optionally deletes a specified length of characters. In the code above, we are inserting `T2` starting at position 1, and deleting 2 character (`M1` in this case).